# How can I output left-to-right NLP dependency graphs?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, graphviz

How do I output a diagram similar to this from depparse output (in JSON or CONLLU)?

Is there a specific tool or specific settings a template in Graphviz?

[image]

I can output something like this in Graphviz (not the same sentence):

[image]

but the flat, left-to-right ordered view is much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the **rank** & **rankdir** attributes.
This input:

```
digraph {
 {
   rank=same
   rankdir=LR
   a->b
   a->c
   a->d
   b->c
   b->e
   f->g
 }
}
```

Produces this:
[image]